# Не удается найти указанный файл C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Всем привет.

Скажите, что в этом коде не правильно ?

Уже 2-й день выдает ошибку "Не удается найти указанный файл"

Вот код:

```
           string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\";

       Process ClientStartProcess = new Process();

       ClientStartProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw";
       ClientStartProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms" + minmem + "M -Xmx" + maxmem + "M -Djava.library.path=" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\natives -cp " + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft/bin/jinput.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + nickname.Text;

       ClientStartProcess.Start();
```

Comment: `Win-R, cmd, javaw` запускается?

Comment: cmd - Да, Win-R нез... java - Да, javaw вот нет...

Comment: @Mozz

 1. [**ЯННП.**](http://lurkmore.so/images/5/53/11318-131945-5c812c9bc8c08b83a416dccd875eac53.jpg)
 2. Если ваш `%PATH%` не включает в себя `javaw`, то на какой результат вы уже два дня рассчитываете?

Comment: Ну а как узнать путь к java?? чтобы запускать его... ибо я делаю не только для себя.

Comment: @Mozz: вам надо общее решение для всех машин, или чтобы запустилось на вашей машине? Скорее всего, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin" или что-то наподобие.

Comment: Мне нужно общее решение  чтобы можно было запустить у меня и у других.

Comment: @Mozz: тогда вам поможет вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3930458/276994 (всё это можно сделать на C#)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. А есть готовый пример на C#?

Comment: @Mozz: нету. А что именно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил использовать что-то вроде такой схемы:

1. Определить через реестр путь к Java.
2. Использовать полный путь к Java на
       компьютере, чтобы запустить
       javaw.exe с нужными аргументами.

Вот код, который реализует такой подход:

```
try
{
    string javaFolder = "";

    RegistryKey javaInstalled = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\");

    if (javaInstalled != null)
    {
        string version = javaInstalled.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();

        RegistryKey javaPath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\" + version + "\\");

        if (javaPath != null)
        {
            javaFolder = javaPath.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();

            string fullPathToJavaW = javaFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "javaw.exe";

            Process ClientStartProcess = new Process();

            ClientStartProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fullPathToJavaW;
            ClientStartProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms" + minmem + "M -Xmx" + maxmem + "M -Djava.library.path=" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\natives -cp " + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft/bin/jinput.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl.jar;" + appData + ".minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + nickname.Text;

            ClientStartProcess.Start();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //
}
```